# Do gas powered fireplace chimneys need to be cleaned if it hasn't been turned fully on for years even during winter?

Tags: chimney

I have a gas powered fireplace which after moving into our house 5 years ago, we havent used even once and the only fire that is in there is the pilot one which remains on even when the switch outside on the wall is off. That is the only fire which exists in there. The fireplace has been fully turned on in total less than 15 minutes in the last 5 years.

So, should I get the chimney cleaned or have it cleaned by outside professionals? Any information would be useful as I don't want to waste money on hiring someone or doing it wrong myself if I don't have to at all.

Comment: A cleaning usually should also cover an inspection.  Cleaning might not be needed, but an inspection is for your safety.  A chimney that CO gas inside when you are sleeping, can mean a forever sleep.  The fireplace itself should also be inspected.  Chimney and fireplace inspections are usually done by two separate people.  One inspects the fireplace is working correctly, and one does the chimney. (two different jobs).

Comment: Burning gas does not leave any residue in a chimney so It should not need cleaning from the burned gas. Our brick chimney has never been cleaned in 45 years of our use. It was originally a wood fireplace with a gas burner as a starter for wood. I installed a gas burner heating ceramic logs. Our chimney has a cap on top to keep animals out. When we use it I   crack a nearby window. It draws OK so I assume it is not blocked. I open the damper when we use it which we rarely do nowadays.

Comment: do you even have a chimney?

Comment: I dont think i have a chimney in a conventional sense, its more of a tv room adornment with pilot fire on. The unit extends outward from the tv room wall not up. from what i can tell, it might be a vent free or direct vent. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

In my part of the world, birds routinely nest in unused chimneys and in fact my house burnt down because of it in 2000.

So, I would say, get them cleaned and inspected at least every two years if unused or every year if using them.